# How should I use an optocoupler to control a 12Vcc load with Arduino?

Tags: relay

I am developing a project to operate a load of about 12Vdc.  I considered the use of an optocoupler to avoid mechanical wear of a relay.  The design I have tried is [this](http://123d.circuits.io/circuits/1573080-optoacoplador-con-arduino):

[image]

This configuration seems to work OK, but I am a biologist and this is my first attempt with an opto of any kind!!!!  I had a lot of trouble with the transistor until I changed to a PNP.  Is this right?  Can it be done with an NPN or even without any transistor at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your load draws a small amount of current (less than about 30 mA current), your 4N35 optocoupler could drive the load directly on 12 volts.

Ignore my use of 4N28 (similar to 4N35). It is the symbol that I had.

It appears that your PNP transistor circuit is something like this :

[image]

The PNP transistor circuit can work well depending upon your load current.  The PNP circuit has some problems with the transistor not turning on fully (and won't be described here).  You may not get the full 12 volts to your Load. But, if it works for your load, then be happy with the PNP circuit.

The circuit below is for a NPN transistor circuit  :

[image]

Using the NPN circuit allows (in this case) for the transistor to turn on fully, leaving almost the full 12 volts for your Load.

Important Note :  The NPN transistor circuit produces an output that is the LOGIC opposite of the PNP circuit.   Notice that for the PNP circuit, a logic 1 to the input of the optocoupler (LED on) turns on power to your Load.

On the NPN circuit, a logic zero (0) to the optocoupler LED is required to turn on your Load.

Another variation of the circuit is below, and does NOT have the reverse logic situation.  In other words, it will behave like the PNP circuit. When LED is on, the Load will be on  :

[image]

You can experiment with the value of R1 in the NPN circuits. You could experiment with lower value, down to 1K (1000 ohms) if you are using a power transistor to drive high current loads.

Comment: Very informative and useful solution to my question Marla.  Thank you very much.